# refreshing select option without reloading a page javascript

Tags: javascript

I have select option in HTML for which i have used Change event listener for triggering some event. Though the event is triggered first but selecting same option for second time without reloading page isn't triggering event. please help

```
 learnPiano.addEventListener("change",function(){
    console.log(learnPiano.value,'value');
    learn.guidePlaying(learnPiano.value);
  })
```

;

Comment: `onchange` is fired when a value _changes_ . Selecting an already selected option doesn't _change_ the value of an select element.

Comment: Try searching better, it's a duplicate - [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877527/html-select-trigger-javascript-onchange-event-even-when-the-option-is-not-cha)

Answer (score 1):

`change` doesn't fire every time. `change` is only fired when the value has actually been changed. when you select the same value the event does not dispatch.

so, instead use `"mouseup"` Even Listener.

Click on select only fires when an option has actually been clicked.
so i believe it will work as you would expect.

```
learnPiano.addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log(learnPiano.value,'value');
    learn.guidePlaying(learnPiano.value);
});
```

## EDIT:

I have Modified the code to clarify because of your last comment.

You must use the `"mouseup"` on the select tag itself.
look at this code snippet and check the console log for the outputs. it works for me on every test.

### you can disregard the CSS code completely it's just for the ease of viewing

```js
// i wasn't sure whare lean was so i created a simple object.
// i'm sure you would be able to implement it
var learn = {
  guidePlaying: function(value) {
    console.log("guidePlaying method works");
    console.log(value);
  }
};


select.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
  
  // this line is decided upon event fire and is the currently selected value
  var selectedValue =  select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  
    console.log(selectedValue,'value');
    learn.guidePlaying(selectedValue);
});
```

```css
select {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select">
      <option value="">Any</option>
      <option value="">kind</option>
      <option value="">of</option>
      <option value="">selection</option>
      <option value="">works</option>
  </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks it really worked for one option but got problem with multiple options

Comment: I've edited the post to clarify it because you said it wasn't working in multiple options. check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Change Event will only trigger when you change your selection.

If a value is already selected & if you are trying to select the same value again, Event will not trigger.

Consider this Select

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

If after selecting `'Volvo'`, again if you try to select 'Volvo', Event will not trigger.