# How to display a select only when other select's option was chosen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have 4 selects on a page and only the first one is visible. Also, the first select has basic prompt string: **Choose person** like this:

```
<select name="post[person_id]">
  <option value="">Choose person</option>
  <option value="1">David</option>
  <option value="2">Sam</option>
  <option value="3">Tobias</option>
</select>
```

Once user chooses some option from the first dropdown, the other 3 selects have to be displayed.

How to implement it?

Comment: Not sure what you need. Can elaborate?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao what are you unsure about?

Comment: Within a change handler for first select show the others. Please show your code attempts.... not really difficult to do this and this isn't a code writing service

Comment: @charlietfl How can I trigger an event that some option was selected?

Comment: listen to change event of `<select>`  http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877527/html-select-trigger-javascript-onchange-event-even-when-the-option-is-not-chan) methods.

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction(){

// fetch new data for the next select. 

//append the new options on next select. 

// make select available or enabled 

}

</script>
```

For the first select use the `onchange` to **fetch** (populate) the options of the **next selects**. And do the same for the following selects.

You can also fetch and make it available in the instance you finish to populate the select.

In case you are not using **jQuery**. You can append the option

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple jquery solution. The key is to use the `.change` event and hook it up to your dropdown(s).

**HTML**

```
    <select id="controllerDD">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="Show 1">Show 1</option>
        <option value="Show 2">Show 2</option>
        <option value="Show All">Show All</option>
    </select>
    <p>DD 1</p>
    <select id="DD1" style="display:none">
        <option value="blah">Select...</option>
        <option value="blah">blah</option>
        <option value="blah">blah</option>
        <option value="blah">blah</option>
    </select>
    <p>DD 2</p>
    <select id="DD2" style="display:none">
        <option value="blah">Select...</option>
        <option value="blah">blah</option>
        <option value="blah">blah</option>
        <option value="blah">blah</option>
    </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#controllerDD').change(function (e) {
    var selected = $(e.currentTarget).val();
    $('#DD1').hide();
    $('#DD2').hide();
    switch (selected) {
        case "Show 1":
            $('#DD1').show();
            break;
        case "Show 2":
            $('#DD2').show();
            break;
        case "Show All":
            $('#DD1').show();
            $('#DD2').show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
})
```