# change form submit location

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to change location where form is submitted because i want that the user picks a domain but when i have submitted the form it didn't worked and when i  have submitted the form without the dropdown it worked

my html:

```
<form method="post" action="http://order.Freehostnoads.usa.cc/register2.php" id="form1">
<table>
<tr><th style="text-align: left;">Free Subdomain<td><input type="text" name="username" size="30" maxlength="25" onkeyup="return ismaxlength(this)">
<select id="domain" size="1" onChange="javascript:chgAction()">
      <option value="http://order.freehostnoads.usa.cc/register2.php" selected="selected">.freehostnoads.usa.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.usa.cc/register2.php">.3eehost.usa.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.usa.cc/register2.php">.3eehosting.usa.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.igg.biz/register2.php">.3eehosting.igg.biz</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.igg.biz/register2.php">.3eehost.igg.biz</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.flu.cc/register2.php">.3eehosting.flu.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.flu.cc/register2.php">.3eehost.flu.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.nut.cc/register2.php">.3eehosting.nut.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.nut.cc/register2.php">.3eehost.nut.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.fg.nut.cc/register2.php">.fg.nut.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.hs.igg.biz/register2.php">.hs.igg.biz</option>
      <option value="http://order.pw.usa.cc/register2.php">.pw.usa.cc</option>
      </select>
```

my javascript:

```
<script>
function chgAction(){
    $('#form1').attr({'action':$('option:selected').attr('value')});
}
</script>
```

the website i want to put this on: http://freehostnoads.usa.cc/free-hosting-signup.php

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set form action through JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701041/how-to-set-form-action-through-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877527/html-select-trigger-javascript-onchange-event-even-when-the-option-is-not-chan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (here at SO). I moved the event handler code out of the tag

Assigning prop or attr is `.prop("name","value")`

Perhaps your free site is removing your links. Have a look with "Inspect" and the console

```js
$(function() {
  $("#domain").on("change",function() {
    $('#form1').prop('action',this.value);
  });
}).change(); // initialise
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="http://order.Freehostnoads.usa.cc/register2.php" id="form1">
<select id="domain" size="1" >
      <option value="">Please select</option>
      <option value="http://order.freehostnoads.usa.cc/register2.php" selected="selected">.freehostnoads.usa.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.usa.cc/register2.php">.3eehost.usa.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.usa.cc/register2.php">.3eehosting.usa.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.igg.biz/register2.php">.3eehosting.igg.biz</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.igg.biz/register2.php">.3eehost.igg.biz</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.flu.cc/register2.php">.3eehosting.flu.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.flu.cc/register2.php">.3eehost.flu.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehosting.nut.cc/register2.php">.3eehosting.nut.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.3eehost.nut.cc/register2.php">.3eehost.nut.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.fg.nut.cc/register2.php">.fg.nut.cc</option>
      <option value="http://order.hs.igg.biz/register2.php">.hs.igg.biz</option>
      <option value="http://order.pw.usa.cc/register2.php">.pw.usa.cc</option>
      </select>
<form>
```

Comment: then you need to look in the console. My code works. Inspect element and see it changes the action. Perhaps your free site removes all http links that goes elsewhere

Comment: ok it changes the action but for a strange thing the register page don't work with the form. i'll try to solve the problem. thanks!