# Is it possible to bind select option On select and not On change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to bind an event when user selected an item from `<select>`
not necessary changed from the default.

`$(select).change();` only works if the item was changed.

i wonder if there is something that works by selecting one of the options even if its the same default option.

```
$('#page_body').on('select', '.pop_pin_select', function() {
});
```

This is what i try so far but it wont work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [HTML select element onchange trigger for already selected option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354367/html-select-element-onchange-trigger-for-already-selected-option).

Comment: You probably want to have a blank option to force a `change` event. Selects simply don't work in the way you're trying to make them work.

Comment: yea that's the worst case scenario, there is a reason i am trying it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way around this; making the option at index 0 the default selected, dynamic and not manually selectable (i.e. *disabled*) and listen for *onchange* as normal, except when changing to index 0. Then *onchange*, set `.options[0]` to chosen *label* and *value* and change selection to it. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rp7xk/1/).

Relevant JavaScript from example

```
document.getElementById('sel')
    .addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.selectedIndex === 0) return;
        this.options[0].value = this.value;
        this.options[0].textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
    }, false);​
```

*onchange* will fire when a user makes the same selection because the index is changing even though the value isn't.

Comment: @downvoter, please explain your downvote in a comment so I can respond to it.